# how do i insert localstorage var in data read url?

Tags: ajax, local-storage

I see my local storage is on the page. I am trying to pull in the user_id and place it in the data URL to build my query. Can someone please let me know what im doing wrong?

```
<!--GET REMOTE JSON DATA-->    
<script>
 var app = new kendo.mobile.Application();
    var theuser = localStorage.getItem('user_ID'); //grab user ID from local     storage
    var IRISalerts = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
read: {
  url: "http://procdev.irisdispatch.com/ws/mobilefunctions.cfc?    method=getAlerts&user_id='+theuser'",
  dataType: "json", // "jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for     same-domain requests
}
```

},

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `.encodeURIComponent()` to encode your query parameters, don't you; it may have invalid url characters ( special characters, etc. ) giving you a headaces. Try out this function, you may use it for object -> query-string conversion ( if you storing json objs in storage ), it performs well for key=value pairs also. For single query parameter `.encodeURIComponent()` does the job...

```
function uriParamNcoder(obj) {
    if (
        Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object String]"
    ) {
        return obj.split('=')
            .map(
                function (part) {
                    return encodeURIComponent(part);
                }
        )
            .join('=')
            .replace(/%20/g, '+');
    }
    var q_str_arr = [];
    objTrace(
        obj,
        function (k, v, trace) {
            var tmp = trace.match(/^\[(.+?)\](.*)$/);
            q_str_arr.push(
                encodeURIComponent(tmp[1]) +
                ((tmp[2] !== void 0) ? encodeURIComponent(tmp[2]) : "") + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v)
            );
        }
    );

    function objTrace(obj, fn) {
        if (
            obj === Object(obj) && (typeof fn === "function")
        ) {
            objParamTracer.apply(
                obj, [obj, fn].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2))
            );
        }
        return obj;
    }

    function objParamTracer(obj, fn, trace) {
        trace || (trace = "");
        if (
            Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]"
        ) {
            obj.forEach(
                function (o, k) {
                    if (o === Object(o)) {
                        return objParamTracer.apply(
                            o, [o, fn].concat(trace + "[]")
                        );
                    } else {
                        return fn.apply(
                            this, [k, o].concat(trace + "[]")
                        );
                    }
                },
                obj
            );
        } else {
            ownEach(
                obj,
                function (p, o) {
                    if (
                        o === Object(o)
                    ) {
                        return objParamTracer.apply(
                            obj, [o, fn].concat(trace + "[" + p + "]")
                        );
                    } else {
                        return fn.apply(
                            this, [p, o].concat(trace + "[" + p + "]")
                        );
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }

    function ownEach(obj, fn) {
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                fn.call(obj, prop, obj[prop]);
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }

    return q_str_arr.join('&').replace(/%20/g, '+');
}
```